# How to relate to the rows' entities in custom sort functions in ng-grid?

Tags: angular-ui, ng-grid

I followed the documentation in https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Sorting-and-filtering
but the only informaiton passed to the custom sort function  are the values of the cells in the relevant column.

I'd like to access other columns within the custom sort function.

e.g.:http://plnkr.co/edit/FvcKQjkUv1eeoYPzjdRD?p=preview
I'd like to sort by name after taking the role into consideration. This would be easy if the row entity was supplied or something of sorts.

Thank you for any assistance.
Yuval

Answer (score 2):

try to implement by header template and the whole control is in your hand fro sorting the callback goes to a function where you can do anything you want

```
var myHeaderCellTemplate = '<div class="ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}" ng-style="{cursor: col.cursor}" ng-class="{ ngSorted: !noSortVisible }">'+
    '<div ng-click="sortByMyPreference()" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText">{{col.displayName}}</div>'+
    '<div class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="ID.down"></div>'+
    '<div class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="ID.up"></div>'+
    '<div class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>'+
    '<div ng-show="col.resizable" '+
          'class="ngHeaderGrip" '+
          'ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" '+
          'ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>';
```

here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OxyV1NlgznEJ8ulNAkt2?p=preview

i have left the implementation of sorting upto you click the Name Tab it will show you an alert and ID.down and ID.up you can toggle by true false to show arrows

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr. I've edited it a bit:
http://plnkr.co/edit/550uOQbKF9TbfjD53zIn?p=preview

As you can see, a simple reordering of the data array doesn't affect the data order in the displayed grid.

Comment: yes it worked when we changed the array to empty or assign any other array the real implementation where i tried this sort of sorting is here http://plnkr.co/edit/sFuCa0?p=preview  in the fiddle sorting on allowance column is done manually and other column is default implementation of ng-grid itself